# Does a straight and very slightly turned out trail of footsteps indicate a problem?

Tags: running, running-form

Obviously your feet shouldn't be turned out a lot while running ([question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/feet-turned-out-while-running) about it), but I've been thinking about whether mine are turned out too much or not.

Also my foot steps are pretty much in a line. I'm not sure if this is normal, it seems reasonable to me when trail running, but should my feet be a bit out to each side when running track?

Photos of my footsteps, once with standard running shoes, relaxed pace, once without, slightly faster pace.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you adducting your legs while running? It doesn't look like you have a thin trail to follow so how come?

Comment: @Emil I do some trail running, but this is not a trail, correct. When I don't pay attention I think (and this test confirms it) I always end up putting my foot steps behind each other in a straight line. I'm not sure if this is good/bad/neutral and that was one reason I posted this question.

Comment: Tensing muscles that are not needed seems wasteful to me. I usually use only the muscles I need when doing things.

Comment: @Emil Certainly makes sense, I'll put some attention to whether I can relax something there to run faster. Thanks. But I'm mostly focused on whether my running style is unhealthy.

Comment: I think you might need expert. I have read an anatomy book and one book about... something with movement but none of them went that much into depth. They had some extreme examples of gait but nothing specific about running. Maybe you could visit the university biomedical library that is where I found books about similar things.